# Exposing a many to many field using Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an event following/signup system that uses Django REST Framework and can't figure out how to properly set this up.

In my events model I have:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='following')
```

Ideally, an authenticated user could use a POST or PATCH to add or remove themselves from the followers record for a given event. Though I'm not really sure what the best way to do that would be.

My current thinking would be to create a serializer that only exposes the followers field, then create an APIView using that serializer with login in the get and post/patch methods to add or remove the specific user.

I'm getting the feeling that this is over-complicating things though. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about using a 'through' model for the M2M relation?

I mean:

```
class Follower(...:
  user = FK user
  event = FK event

...
followers = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through=Follower ...)
...
```

In this case you are able to create quickly a model serializer and a generic view for the model Follower. In order to add or remove a user to an event you just send POST or DELETE requests to this resource

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, it's also what I was specifically trying to avoid. For various other reasons I wanted to avoid a separate model, but it looks like I can't.

Comment: For me It looks better and clearer to POST when you have a new follower instead of using PATCH. Additionally, you always have the separate model, by default it's just implicit.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately many-to-many relationships *always* use an intermediary model. There are hacky horrible solutions involving compressing multiple indexes into a single string field and the like out there. They are universally terrible and you should never do it!

Comment: @Shayne, yes of course there is always an intermediary model, I didn't claim opposite in my answer. By default Django creates such model implicitly. In my answer I suggested to denote that model explicitly by using the 'through' argument in order to simplify creating serializers/views for this model.

Comment: @AndreyKaygorodov , I was responding to jmickela's comment